# add description to shipping method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Please Help me on this topic I want to add **description** for shipping methods. For example, If **Flat Rate** shipping method is on, than there is a **text box** for **add description** in admin side, add content in this textbox and showing that text in frontend . Same as all shipping method from admin and that label will be display on front-end. Please give me a way to make easy.